# Python SubProcess call with application server

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm getting -2147024809 returned when I execute the following statement

```
subprocess.call([r"C:\Windows\CCM\VAppLauncher.exe" , r"/launch 'Mozilla Firefox 1.0'"])
```

In the command prompt, when I execute

```
C:\Windows\CCM\VAppLauncher.exe /launch "Mozilla Firefox 1.0"
```

it launches Firefox with no problems. Is the fact that "Mozilla Firefox" is quoted causing an issue here?

Comment: i think your call should look like this: subprocess.call([r"C:\Windows\CCM\VAppLauncher.exe" , r"/launch", "'Mozilla Firefox 1.0'"]) if that doesn't work try to remove the quotes from last part

Comment: That worked when I removed the quotes from the last part, thanks

Comment: glad i could help. When using subprocess.call always remember that each parameter in your call (as from cmd, command line or anything else) has to be a separate list element. In your case this was the path to executable, the /launch argument and then the string with name of an app. your original solution would have executed /path/to/an/app '/launch "Mozilla Firefox 1.0"' or something like that where the whole string would be treated as an argument to your launcher